# how do i convert nested dictionary within a dictionary to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary as below:

`nested_dict = { 'dictB': {'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'}}}`

basically i want the value of key `dictB` as a dictionary.

i tried doing

1. `dict(nested_dict["dictB"].values())`
   but i got error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-275e88e1ed17> in <module>
----> 1 dict(nested_dict["dictB"].values())

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

2. `nested_dict["dictB"].values()` . i got
   `dict_values([{'key_1': 'value_1'}])`  which is a list itself but i want it to be dictionary
   is there any way i can get the dictionary of dictB key.

Comment: How about `nested_dict["dictB"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's already a dict, you should be able to get it directly without any transformation:

```
dict_b = nested_dict["dictB"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the dictionary in the value assigned to the `dictB` key,
you can access it simply by accessing the value of the key of the `nested_dict` dictionary as follows:
`nested_dict['dictB']`